# Javascript property access without variable assignment or declaration: Why?

Tags: javascript, properties, singleton, prototypal-inheritance

I've inherited a fairly large code-base and there seems to be a bit of a coding pattern going on, but I cannot for the life of me see what it does.

Essentially, the app contains of a number of classes, each with a sort of factory function that enforces singletons. However, there appears to be a redundant line that just accesses an object property without assigning it to a variable, or setting the property.

For example:

```
myApp.dialog.AddEvent = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() { ... },
  render: function() { ... },
  refresh: function() { ... }
});

myApp.dialog._addEvent; // <-- What is this for?

myApp.dialog.addEvent = function() {
  var d = myApp.dialog._addEvent;
  if (!d) {
    d = myApp.dialog._addEvent = new myApp.dialog.AddEvent();
  }
  return d;
}
```

What does the line `myApp.dialog._addEvent` actually do, if anything? The number of times it appears throughout the app suggests it isn't just a typo. Possibly some kind of property instantiation hack for old IE or something like that?

Comment: That line you're asking about doesn't do anything.  It doesn't cause that property to be defined, it doesn't cause an error if the property doesn't already exist.  In fact, there is no difference in the `myApp.dialog` object before or after that line.

Comment: Thanks, yep that's what I thought. I think it may be a misguided attempt at the equivalent variable declaration without assignment (e.g. `var addEvent;`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line of code:

```
myApp.dialog._addEvent;
```

doesn't do anything. It doesn't cause that property to be defined, it doesn't cause an error if the property doesn't already exist. In fact, there is no difference in the `myApp.dialog` object before or after that line.

As you surmise, the author may think that the line in question defines the property on the object (which it doesn't) and predefining the property on the object isn't needed for the code the follows anyway.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! And now I get to delete a bunch of code which is one of my favourite pastimes. :)

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the source for `myApp.dialog._addEvent`, it's impossible to say exactly what happens. Typically a single line containing a variable being accessed will do nothing:

```
var a = {
    wat: 'wat'
};
a.wat; //this does nothing
```

However, it's possible that an [accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get) was written for the property, which could cause side-effects (alternatively you might see [`__defineGetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter), or [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)).

```
var a = {
    get wat() {
        console.log('wat!');
        return 'wat';
    }
};
a.wat; //this writes 'wat!' to the console
```

This sort of programming is generally considered bad-practice because it violates the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

That said, just because it's bad practice doesn't mean that it's not happening.

Comment: I think you can tell from the code that follows that the intended data for the `_addEvent` property is an object not a property with an accessor.

Comment: @jfriend00, I agree that *it's highly probable*, however it's possible to do some really crazy things with accessors and mutators, so it's worth mentioning the other possibilities.

Comment: Yes, kudos to you for finding something that the line "could" be doing, but I don't think we have any evidence that that is what is actually happening here.

Comment: Ah interesting! I didn't even think of ES5 accessors. However, I've searched the entire codebase and `myApp.dialog._addEvent` appears nowhere outside of that class so it really must just be a redundant line.